# Iterating through cells on NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsview

I am building a `NSTableView` to show an array of file paths (`directoriesArray`).  I have built the NSTableView on the main.storyboard and I have used this code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return _directoriesArray.count;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return [_directoriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    NSTableView *tableView = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"User has selected row %ld", (long)tableView.selectedRow);
    
    NSLog(@"%@",[_directoriesArray objectAtIndex:tableView.selectedRow]);
    
}

//changes font of everything
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTextFieldCell *cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
    [cell setFont:[self quicksand:15.0f]];
    return cell;
}
```

This works perfectly.

I now want to iterate through each cell on the `NSTableView` and edit them with if statements.

I have tried replacing the

```
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
```

block, with:

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    NSTableCellView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    if(view == nil){
        NSTableCellView *view = [[NSTableCellView alloc]initWithFrame:[tableView frame]];
        view.identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    }
    NSTextField *textfield = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    [textfield setStringValue:[_directoriesArray objectAtIndex:tableView.selectedRow]];
    [textfield setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [view addSubview:textfield];
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return view;
}
```

but this is showing empty rows! What am I doing wrong?!

---

Weird thing -  When I click on a cell when the modified code is running `tableViewSelectionDidChange` is called and I still get the logs perfectly.... ?!

---

## edit

I have updated the code (to the best of my ability - which is poorly):

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    NSTableCellView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    if(view == nil){
        NSTableCellView *view = [[NSTableCellView alloc]initWithFrame:[tableView frame]];
        view.identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; //turned this off
        NSTextField *textfield;
        textfield.autoresizingMask = NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin; //changed to autoresizing
        [textfield setStringValue:[_directoriesArray objectAtIndex:row]]; //changed to row
        [textfield setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        [view addSubview:textfield];
        [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    }
    return view;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems confused. The subject says it's about iterating through the cells of a table view, but nothing in it seems to be about that, as such.

You said you replaced the `-tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:` method with a `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` method. The first is appropriate for a cell-based table view. The second is for a view-based table view. By changing your delegate method, you're sort of changing the table from cell-based to view-based.

For a programmatically-created table view, I believe that the delegate methods are the only thing which determine whether it's cell-based or view-based. However, for a table view created in a storyboard, that is also specified in the storyboard. Mismatching the two is sure to cause trouble.

So, if you want to switch from cell-based to view-based, make sure to change it in the storyboard, too. In that case, you get to set up the prototype cell view in the storyboard, too.

You're creating your cell views in code, though. Since you're not turning `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` off (it's on by default), your cell view and its text field are effectively using the springs-and-struts model for layout. The table view will set the frame of the cell view. However, you're initially setting it to be huge — as big as the whole table view. Furthermore, the text field is initially positioned at (0, 0, 100, 30). You need to set its `autoresizingMask` to determine how its size should change when the cell view's size changes. And, if it is set to resize as its superview resizes, then you'll want the superview to have a more reasonable size to begin with (or for the text field to be nearly as unreasonable).

The scenario you want to avoid is that the cell view starts huge, the text field is small relative to that, the text field is configured to stay roughly proportional to the cell view's size, so when the table view resizes the cell view to the size of a cell it shrinks the text field to a minuscule size.

Before you create the cell view, you ask the table view to get one from its reuse queue. This is good. However, if it gets one from its reuse queue, then that one already has a text field. You shouldn't create and add a new text field every time. The creation of the text field should be inside the `if(view == nil)` statement.

When you set the text field's `stringValue`, you are indexing into your `_directoriesArray` using `tableView.selectedRow`. This is wrong. First, the table view may not have any `selectedRow`. In fact, it is unlikely to when it's first being set up. I'm surprised you're not getting an exception due to indexing into the array with a bad index (-1). Second, the method you're implementing is called for all the different rows. You don't want to give them all the same value. The method is passed a `row` parameter which indicates for which row the view has been requested.

Just for good measure, I would connect the cell view's `textField` outlet to the text field that you create. `NSTableCellView` sometimes does special things based on its `textField` outlet being connected. (For example, it uses the contents of the text field for the accessibility text of the cell.)

---

In your new code from your edit, there are new problems.

You are turning `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` off for the cell view. I was not suggesting that you turn it off. I was only explaining that it was on and what the consequences of that are. For the cell view, you should leave it on and let the table view decide whether it wants to turn it off. In general, the controller code which inserts a view into a view hierarchy decides whether or not to turn that off. However, there's still controller code out there which is not aware of auto layout or that property and so it should be left on by default. That way, auto-layout-aware controller code can set it as it wants while auto-layout-naive controller code gets the old behavior that it depends on. (Technically, we can't assume whether `NSTableView`'s internals are auto-layout-aware in this sense or not.)

You are no longer creating a text field at all. You declare the variable, but you don't create an instance. The variable just remains `nil` (assuming you're using ARC). You should still allocate and initialize the text field. However, you should use a frame rect for the cell view and the text field which have the spatial relationship you want them to have. Springs-and-struts only ever maintains relationships. So, you need to start with a sensible relationship and the `autoresizingMask` is used from then on to maintain it.

If you decide to use auto layout to relate the text field to its superview (the cell view), then you could turn `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` off *on the text field*. But then you would need to establish constraints to relate the text field to the cell view. In this case, the initial frames of the cell view and text field would not matter.

In your new code, you are only setting the `stringValue` of the text field when it's created. But you need to set it if it's obtained from the reuse queue, too. Doing this will be much easier if you set the `textField` property of the cell view when both are created.

Here is a revised version of your code:

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    NSTableCellView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    if(view == nil){
        NSTableCellView *view = [[NSTableCellView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        view.identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
        NSTextField *textfield = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSInsetRect(view.frame, 2, 2)];
        textfield.autoresizingMask = NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin; //changed to autoresizing
        textfield.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
        [view addSubview:textfield];
        view.textField = textfield;
    }
    view.textField.stringValue = [_directoriesArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I have tried to update my code to the best of my ability but it is still not working (see updated question). I don't know how to go about doing what you mentioned in the second paragraph and in the last would you be able to expand on it a little more? Like where do I seem to be changing the delegate method?

Comment: I have updated my answer with clarifications, comments on the new code you added to your question, and an adjusted version of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anyway to make the `NSTableCellView` width automatic to the textfields with with the string/?

Comment: The table determines the width of its columns. The width of the column determines the width of the cell views within that column. There's no built-in way to make the table view adjust its columns' widths to match their content. (If the user double-clicks a column divider, the column will be sized to match its cells' content or the result from the `-tableView:sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:` delegate method, but you can't provoke that programmatically.) If you want a column to have a particular width, you need to compute that width yourself and set it on the `NSTableColumn` object.